# Remove selected value from dropdown using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 drop down field with same name. I need to remove selected option from second drop down field. I tried with this:

```
$(".salaryAdd option:selected").remove();
```

Comment: please share your html code

Comment: your code looks liek Jquery, But you are asking solution in javascript. I am going to edit your question to tag jquery as well.

Comment: $("#selectBox option[value='option1']").remove();

Comment: Post your HTML code to get more help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by selecting the second select with [`eq`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) and clearing it's value using [`val`](https://api.jquery.com/val/) like this:

```js
$(".salaryAdd:eq(1)").val('');
//---------------^ eq is zero index based
// or $(".salaryAdd").eq(1).val('');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="salaryAdd">
  <option selected>hi</option>
</select>
<select class="salaryAdd">
  <option selected>hi</option>
</select>
<select class="salaryAdd">
  <option selected>hi</option>
</select>
```